# Is it suggestible to have 2 separate tables for Read and DML

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

We have a table that has more than 600 columns and more than 30M rows as of now. There are more than 20 columns, where Index is defined and the table is distributed among 5 partitions.

There are more than 5 processes (writing to specific partition), that run in real-time, and they Insert/Update to this table (approx 10k Inserts and 1-2 Million updates per day).

Also, there are more than 20 processes, containing underlying procedures/views/queries, that read from this table continuously. The `select` from the table, despite indexes, is slow, if I compare it to other databases.

Now we are planning to redesign and split the table, as many columns are obsolete now, and many columns are valid only for a specific partition. So we want to have 5 separate tables, one for each partition with attributes specific to that partition.

> **Would it be suggestible to have 2 separate set of tables, one for DMLs and one for Select, and synchronize them via triggers? Any other
> suggestions regarding the split/sync of the tables would be really
> appreciated.**

I tried to replicate the scenario with 2 partitions below. The first table is the one being used currently, which we would delete and create 2 separate tables, for each partitions, with attributes specific to that partition.

Existing Table: `t` , which we would delete later. Table is partition by `REGION`

```
+----+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| ID | REGION | NAME  | COL_1 | COL_2 | COL_3 |
+----+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | A      | FOO   |    12 | Y     |       |
|  2 | A      | BAR   |    13 | N     |       |
|  3 | B      | ALPHA |    14 |       |     1 |
+----+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

New Table: `t_A`

```
+----+--------+------+-------+-------+
| ID | REGION | NAME | COL_1 | COL_2 |
+----+--------+------+-------+-------+
|  1 | A      | FOO  |    12 | Y     |
|  2 | A      | BAR  |    13 | N     |
+----+--------+------+-------+-------+
```

New Table: `t_B`

```
+----+--------+-------+-------+-------+
| ID | REGION | NAME  | COL_1 | COL_3 |
+----+--------+-------+-------+-------+
|  3 | B      | ALPHA |    14 |     1 |
+----+--------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: "...The select from the table, despite indexes, is slow..." -- It shouldn't be, unless you are reading a massive number of rows on each SELECT. My guess is you don't have the best indexes in place. Maybe the solution is just to tune the SELECTs. If this is the case, please include them so we can help you tuning them.

Comment: The very fact that the table has "more than 600 columns" is highly suggestive of a seriously flawed design.  Rigorously design all of your tables to Third Normal Form, and 95% of your problems will disappear on their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost certainly do not want to manually create separate sets of tables for reading and writing. Readers and writers do not block each other in Oracle, and unless you have some extremely rare scenario, those 25 concurrent processes are not causing hot-block performance issues.

Splitting tables is more likely to create new problems with caching and replication. Doubling the amount of data also means there is potentially twice as much data to try to cram into memory. And a custom replication program will significantly decrease write performance because all writes are duplicated and there will be more context switching for the triggers.

The only time it makes sense to create separate tables for reads and writes is if you already have a read-only system, like if you use data guard to create a logical standby database. In that case you can use Oracle's built-in replication, which will likely be faster and more accurate than a custom version. And the second database might help performance if your first database is low on resources. (Ideally, it would always be faster to keep everything in a single database, but realistically, your servers can only grow so large.)

As others have mentioned, you should probably invest more time in tuning your existing queries before thinking about separating your tables.